# Writing to 0xb8000000 yields output on screen without any print statements such as `printf`

Tags: c, dos

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
  char far *v = (char far*)0xb8000000;
  clrscr();

  *v = 'w';
  v += 2;
  *v = 'e';

  getch();
}
```

Output is: `we`

I don't get how the output is getting printed without any `printf` or other print statements.

Comment: Plz format teh codez properly and incrs ur accpt r8. (for the record, this was funnier before the flurry of 9 or 10 edits in less than 5 minutes).

Comment: Wow, writing to an arbitrary address in memory. This can spectacularly crash or cause other undefined behavior.

Comment: @Ebo If you're going to do something stupid, you might as well do it in a blaze of glory and segfaults.

Comment: What platform is this running on?

Comment: 9 edits in about a minute!  Is that some kind of record?

Comment: Wow! This code is nearly old as me!!! How many years I din't see someone accessing the character memory buffer directly! And with a "char far!" Real mode DOS!

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think 0xb8000000 was the address to the beginning of video memory in the Old Days

Comment: Yea, recently dev'd a hobby OS, and used this memory space to make sure keyboard IRQ was working.

Comment: @Andrew: `9 edits in about a minute! Is that some kind of record` : Multiple people trying to correct the same text but in different ways, this is what is called a race condition... :-)

Comment: @esaj: 0xB800:0000, to be exact.

Comment: There is a single thing I want to know: where someone in 2011 can find a C real mode compiler for DOS (or other real mode OS) with the conio.h header and everything else... Mmmmh... found there is still the Borland C++ 5.5 and the Turbo C 2.01 . Some things never die, eh? Ok... The real question then is where this example was found? Mmmh... Perhaps from here http://www.coolinterview.com/interview/12167/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a x86 **real-mode** IBM PC program that assumes CGA/EGA/VGA compatible graphics adapter in color text mode mapped at the default memory location (B800:0000); it is basically from the era of MS-DOS (1980s/1990s). In any case it's very old school!

```
char far *v=(char far*)0xb8000000;
```

Memory address (in real mode) of the video buffer (use `0xb0000000` if you have an old Hercules)

```
clrscr();
```

Clears the screen

```
*v='w';
```

Writes at row `0`, column `0` the character `w`

```
v+=2;
```

Skips `2 bytes` (in the character mode the buffer is interleaved: `1 byte` for the character and `1 byte` for the color. `1 bit` for the flashing, `3 bits` for the background *0-7* and `4 bits` for the foreground *0-15*, packed in this way: `foreground + 16 * background + 128 if you want flashing`)

```
*v='e';
```

Writes at row `0`, column `1` the character `e`

```
getch();
```

Waits for a key

Now a link about the [CGA Text Mode Format](http://www.shikadi.net/moddingwiki/B800_Text), for those that FEEL the need of knowing how the "old generation" did it, before "Windows" came (and even before all that "Linux" came :-) ). Ah... and another link (a wiki this time) for those that still don't know what [REAL-MODE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_mode) is.

Comment: @paercebal if you think my explanation isn't complete enough, the next time I'll have you use the INT 10h of the BIOS to write on the screen :-) :-) :-) ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H ), but remember (to quote the wiki) `INT 10h is fairly slow`! :-) (if it isn't clear, it's a joke)

Comment: I just finished the article on Real Mode, and my final thought was "Hey, I'm SOOOO glad I was too young to code in these environments!", so I guess I will pass the "INT 10h" one for tonight... ^_^ ...

Answer (score 9):

He's writing directly to the video buffer which is usually sitting at that address.

Also, this is seriously old school graphics manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's displayed is because `0xB8000000` [is the address where video memory starts](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_0xB8000000).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what platform it is, and it's apparently not one that would crash this nasty code.

`0xb8000000` on the legacy DOS platform was the video memory buffer, so in text mode, you could write characters there directly. See here: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_0xB8000000

Answer (score 0):

First, it gets the address of the beginning of the video buffer.  It then clears the screen, and starts adding text to the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the beginning of the video memory address space. What is written to memory here will be displayed on the screen.